# How to use paths with locale inside YAML localization files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

In the localization files of my Ruby on Rails application I have a number of paths like this:

```
en:
  hello_html: "Feel free to <a href=\"/contact\">contact us</a> at any time."
```

The problem is that this points to `mydomain.com/contact` rather than `mydomain.com/en/contact` or `mydomain.com/fr/contact`.

How can this be done **without** manually passing the locale (e.g. using interpolation)?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the translation system in the wrong way. You should use it like this:

```
# en.yml
  hello_html: "Feel free to %{contact_link} at any time."

# view
<%= t('hello_html', contact_link: link_to("Contact", contact_path(locale: current_locale)) %>
```

---

Even more nested!

```
<% contact_str = t('menus.contact') %>
<% contact_link = link_to contact_str, contact_path %>
<%= t('hello_html', contact_link: contact_link) %>
```